# How to load test data from test/fixtures yml file in Rails units

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, yaml

How to load test data from test/fixtures yml file in Rails units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixtures/xxxs.yml

```
- one:
    clm1: test
    clm2: test
```

test/unit/xxx.rb

```
test "load_yml_obj" do
  assert_not_nil xxxs(:one)
end
```